# let $\mu^{*} (A)$ be an outer measure and define $\nu^{*}$ as the next 'outer measure'. Are $\mu^{*}$ and $\nu^{*}$ equal?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu^{*} (A)$ be an outer measure and define $\nu^{*}$ as the next 'outer measure'. Are $\mu^{*}$ and $\nu^{*}$ equal?

Chose an $\epsilon > 0$. We define $\nu_{\epsilon}^{*}$ exactly the same as $\mu^{*} (A)$, but with the restriction that each covering we use to cover A, must have a minimal length of $\epsilon$. After that we let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. like this:

$\nu (A) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \nu_{\epsilon}^{*}(A)$

Are $\nu(A)$ and $\mu^*(A)$ the same?

I don't seem to see how this fails to work, but maybe there is a sneaky little counterexample that lets this fail.

I was thinking about the Lebesgue measure and an interval which is smaller than epsilon say $[a,b)$ with $\mu([a,b)) = b-a < \epsilon$. But I don't seem to see how to make a smart covering any hints?

Comment: Minimal length of a cover?  So your measure space is a metric space? What is the kind of measure space you have in mind? Is it $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I had indeed $\mathbb{R}$ in mind, but one can of course also take an other measure space which could work for a counterexample. for example  
$(\mathbb{N},P(\mathbb{N}), \phi)$, where $\phi$ is the counting measure